# how to initialize a 2D array inside a class while creating and object of it

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, c++11

I have a class with private pointer to pointer (double pointer), which I am using to create a 2D array.

```
class Arr2D{
    int **arr;
    public:
        Arr2D(int row, int col){
            arr = new int*[r];
            for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
                arr[i] = new int[col];
            }
        }
}
```

I want to initialize this array while creating an object of it as below

```
int main(){
    Arr2D obj(2,2) = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
}
```

how can I initialize the array as show above.

Comment: And what exactly is happening with your current code?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I am getting this error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘=’

Comment: @OmidCompSCI do I need to overload assignment operator

Comment: A `int**` is no 2d array. One of the most important properties of an array is that its elements are continuous in memory. What you're trying to do here is a no-no. Use one dimension and calculate a linear index from `x` and `y` indices.

Comment: @Swordfish even if I user an array it need to be dynamic an I need to initialize it in the same way `Arr2D obj(2,3) = {1,2,  3,4}`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use std::vector?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I can use `vector` inside the `class Arr2D` instead of `int **arr` but I don't think it will solve the issue, I have created `class` to perform actions like matrix manipulation and other stuff with the 2D array

Comment: @Abhishek take a look at https://zcrou.com/blog/dev/nested-initializers

Comment: @Swordfish `std::initializer_list` definitely going to help, thanks for sharing the post :)

Comment: You don't state what the problem or error is. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to do that. Consider that you wont be creating a matrix but a list of lists of integers. But you can handle it as a matrix if you want. Take a look at this code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <initializer_list>
# include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Arr2D {
private:
    vector<vector<int>> Arr;

public:
    Arr2D(initializer_list<vector<int>> p) {
        this->Arr = p;
    }

    void Print () {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->Arr.size (); i++) {
            cout << "row " << i << ": [";

            for (int j = 0; j < this->Arr.at (i).size (); j++) {
                cout << this->Arr.at(i).at (j) << " ";
            }

            cout << "]" << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Arr2D obj {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    obj.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
row 0: [1 2 3 ]
row 1: [4 5 6 ]
```